# Limit and Isolation points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have attempted a question that says to prove that the set of isolated points of a countable complete metric space X forms a dense subset of X.

### My Attempt

It has been shown previously that the closure of any $S\subset X$ is equal to the disjoint Union of its limit points and its isolation points. Since $X\subset X$ and is countable it then follows that $\overline{X}=X=L\bigcup I$ where I is the set of isolation points of X and L is the set of limit points of X. Since the countable Union of nowhere dense sets has an empty interior it follows that L has an empty interior. But $\overline{L}=L$. This then implies that L is nowhere dense which consequently results in $I$ being a dense subset of X.

---

The main part I am concerned about is the beginning of the proof in which I state that the X is equal to the disjoint Union of L and I. It seems like it should work since it is stated that X is countable but I have my concerns. Also this question is from "Introduction to Topology by Gamelin and Greene". Any corrections, conformations or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to worry about closures here. The statement for a point of $x$ being isolated is "there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)=\left\{x\right\}$" (where $B_\epsilon(x)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $x$). The negation of this is "for all $\epsilon>0$ $B_\epsilon(x)\neq\left\{x\right\}$", and you can show that this is equivalent to $x$ being a limit point. In other words, a point of $X$ is either isolated or a limit point, so this gives the disjoint union you want.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! @LuizCordeiro